# Middleware HTTP test passing when it shouldn't

Tags: go, middleware, go-http, go-testing

I've written some middleware that checks to make sure a JWT token in valid:

```
func JwtVerify(next http.Handler) http.Handler {
    return http.HandlerFunc(func(rw http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {

        //Get the token from the header
        header := r.Header.Get("Authorization")

        //If Authorization is empty, return a 403
        if header == "" {
            rw.WriteHeader(http.StatusForbidden)
            json.NewEncoder(rw).Encode(ErrorMsg{ Message: "Missing Authentication Token" })
            return
        }

        header = strings.Split(header, "Bearer ")[1]

        token, err := jwt.Parse(header, func(token *jwt.Token) (i interface{}, err error) {
            if _, ok := token.Method.(*jwt.SigningMethodHMAC); !ok {
                 return nil, fmt.Errorf("unexpected signing method: %v", token.Header["alg"])
            }
            // TODO: REMOVE THE SECRET
            return []byte("MyTestSecret"), nil
        })

       // Return the error
        if err != nil {
            rw.WriteHeader(http.StatusForbidden)
            json.NewEncoder(rw).Encode(ErrorMsg{Message: err.Error()})
            return
        }

        if token.Valid {
            log.Println("JWT Token is valid")
            next.ServeHTTP(rw, r)
        }
    })
}
```

I've Tried to write some tests for this, but I just can grasp where I'm going wrong, the test should fail because the token is invalid but its still passing:

```
func TestJwtVerify(t *testing.T) {
    token := "Bearer eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJpYXQiOjE1ODcwNTIzMTcsImV4cCI6MTU4NzA1MjkxNywic2Vzc2lvbi1kYXRhIjoiVGVzdC5NY1Rlc3RGYWNlQG1haWwuY29tIn0.f0oM4fSH_b1Xi5zEF0VK-t5uhpVidk5HY1O0EGR4SQQ"
    req, err := http.NewRequest("GET", "/jwt", nil)
    if err != nil {
        t.Fatal(err)
    }
    req.Header.Set("Authorization", token)

    testHandler := http.HandlerFunc(func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        if r.Response.StatusCode == 403 {
            t.Fatalf("Response should be 200 for a valid JWT Token")
        }
    })

    rw := httptest.NewRecorder()
    handler := JwtVerify(testHandler)
    handler.ServeHTTP(rw, req)
}
```

Can someone explain where I'm going wrong?

Comment: JwtVerify never calls testHandler if verification fails. Do your assertions on the recorder (i.e. [rw.Code](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/httptest/#ResponseRecorder.Code) or [rw.Result()](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/httptest/#ResponseRecorder.Result)), not within testHandler. `r.Response` only makes sense on the client, never on the server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've got a couple of issues.

First, your test provides a `testHandler` function which should run on any errors, but your `JwtVerify` function only runs the next handler if the token is valid:

```
if token.Valid {
    log.Println("JWT Token is valid")
    next.ServeHTTP(rw, r)
}
```

so you've made sure `testHandler` will never be run when the token is invalid, and therefore your test will not fail.

Your second problem is here:

```
if r.Response.StatusCode == 403 {
    t.Fatalf("Response should be 200 for a valid JWT Token")
}
```

Per the documentation for `http.Request`:

> Response is the redirect response which caused this request to be
>   created. This field is only populated during client redirects.

and since this request is not in response to a client redirect, the `Response` field will not be populated, and in particular the status code will not be determined by the headers you wrote to your `http.ResponseWriter`. In general you can't obtain the status code in this way, and the normal way would be to have an earlier middleware wrap the `http.ResponseWriter`, and obtain the status from that wrapper writer after the middleware that wrote the status returns.

As mentioned in a comment, the right way to go about this is to examine your `httptest.ResponseRecorder` for the status code, since its purpose is to examine HTTP responses during tests.

Comment: "The normal way would be to have an earlier middleware wrap the http.ResponseWriter" Not in tests, though. [The httptest.Recorder.Result method](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/httptest/#ResponseRecorder.Result) returns the response as it would have been received by a client (near-enough anyway).

Comment: @Peter: Whether it's used for a test or not is incidental here. Wrapping the writer for no other purpose than to allow tests to access it would certainly not be normal, if that's what you mean.